# Seemingly inconsistent results when profiling memory in Go

Tags: memory, time, go, profiling

I have recently been running some numerical codes written in Go on large datasets and have been encountering memory management issues. While attempting to profile the problem, I have measured the memory usage of my program in three different ways: with Go's `runtime/pprof` package, with the unix `time` utility, and by manually adding up the size of the data that I allocated. These three methods do not give me consistent results.

Below is a simplified version of the code that I am profiling. It allocates several slices, puts values at every index and places each of them inside of a parent slice:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "runtime/pprof"
    "unsafe"
    "flag"
)

var mprof = flag.String("mprof", "", "write memory profile to this file")

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    N := 1<<15
    psSlice := make([][]int64, N)
    _ = psSlice
    size := 0

    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        ps := make([]int64, 1<<10)
        for i := range ps { ps[i] = int64(i) }
        psSlice[i] = ps
        size += int(unsafe.Sizeof(ps[0])) * len(ps)
    }

    if *mprof != "" {
        f, err := os.Create(*mprof)
        if err != nil { panic(err) }
        pprof.WriteHeapProfile(f)
        f.Close()
    }

    fmt.Printf("total allocated: %d MB\n", size >> 20)
}
```

Running this with the command `$ time time -f "%M kB" ./mem_test -mprof=out.mprof` results in the output:

```
total allocated: 256 MB
1141216 kB

real    0m0.150s
user    0m0.031s
sys 0m0.113s
```

Here the first number, 256 MB, is just the size of the arrays computed from `unsafe.Sizeof` and the second number, 1055 MB, is what `time` reports. Running the pprof tool results in

```
(pprof) top1
Total: 108.2 MB
   107.8  99.5%  99.5%    107.8  99.5% main.main
```

These results scale smoothly in the way you would expect them to for slices of smaller or larger lengths.

Why don't these three number line up more closely?

Comment: just run your code on my machine and got "total allocated: 1024 MB" (OS X 10.9.5)

Comment: also what version of go are you using, what is the target architecture you're using?

Comment: There were errors in my example code which I have now corrected.

I am running Go 1.3.3 for linux/amd64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to provide an error free example. Let's start with the basic numbers. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "unsafe"
)

func WriteMatrix(nm [][]int64) {
    for n := range nm {
        for m := range nm[n] {
            nm[n][m]++
        }
    }
}

func NewMatrix(n, m int) [][]int64 {
    a := make([]int64, n*m)
    nm := make([][]int64, n)
    lo, hi := 0, m
    for i := range nm {
        nm[i] = a[lo:hi:hi]
        lo, hi = hi, hi+m
    }
    return nm
}

func MatrixSize(nm [][]int64) int64 {
    size := int64(0)
    for i := range nm {
        size += int64(unsafe.Sizeof(nm[i]))
        for j := range nm[i] {
            size += int64(unsafe.Sizeof(nm[i][j]))
        }
    }
    return size
}

var nm [][]int64

func main() {
    n, m := 1<<15, 1<<10
    var ms1, ms2 runtime.MemStats
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&ms1)
    nm = NewMatrix(n, m)
    WriteMatrix(nm)
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&ms2)
    fmt.Println(runtime.GOARCH, runtime.GOOS)
    fmt.Println("Actual:  ", ms2.TotalAlloc-ms1.TotalAlloc)
    fmt.Println("Estimate:", n*3*8+n*m*8)
    fmt.Println("Total:   ", ms2.TotalAlloc)
    fmt.Println("Size:    ", MatrixSize(nm))

    // check top VIRT and RES for COMMAND peter
    for {
        WriteMatrix(nm)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go build peter.go && /usr/bin/time -f "%M KiB" ./peter
amd64 linux
Actual:   269221888
Estimate: 269221888
Total:    269240592
Size:     269221888
^C
Command exited with non-zero status 2
265220 KiB
$

$ top
VIRT 284268 RES 265136 COMMAND peter
```

Is this what you expected?

See `MatrixSize` for the correct way to calculate the memory size.

In the infinite loop that allows us to use the `top` command, pin the matrix as resident by updating it.

What results do you get when you run this program?

---

BUG:

Your result from `/usr/bin/time` is  `1056992 KiB` which too large by a factor of four. It's a bug in your version of `/usr/bin/time`, `ru_maxrss` is reported in KBytes not pages. My version of Ubuntu has been patched.

References:

[Re: GNU time: incorrect results](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.utils.help/u1MOsHL4bhg)

[time-1.7 counts rusage wrong on Linux](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-utils/2013-02/msg00019.html)

[GNU Project Archives: time](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/time/)

[“time” 1.7-24 source package in Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/time/1.7-24). `ru_maxrss` is reported in KBytes not pages. (Closes: #649402)

[#649402 - [PATCH] time overestimates max RSS by a factor of 4 - Debian Bug report logs](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=649402)

> Subject: Fix ru_maxrss reporting Author: Richard Kettlewell
>   Bug-Debian: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=649402
>
> ```
> --- time-1.7.orig/time.c
> +++ time-1.7/time.c
> @@ -392,7 +398,7 @@
>              ptok ((UL) resp->ru.ru_ixrss) / MSEC_TO_TICKS (v));
>         break;
>       case 'M':       /* Maximum resident set size.  */
> -       fprintf (fp, "%lu", ptok ((UL) resp->ru.ru_maxrss));
> +       fprintf (fp, "%lu", (UL) resp->ru.ru_maxrss);
>         break;
>       case 'O':       /* Outputs.  */
>         fprintf (fp, "%ld", resp->ru.ru_oublock);
> ```

Comment: I have corrected the errors in my example code.

When I run your code I get results consistent with yours. However I still get a factor of four from the time utility.

Comment: Here is what happened when I ran your code:

$ go build peter.go && /usr/bin/time -f "%M KiB" ./peter

amd64 linux

Actual:   269256384

Estimate: 269221888

Total:    269355416

Size:     269221888

1056992 KiB

Which still shows a factor of four difference.

I decided to investigate whether my `time` is working correctly. I placed a `for { }` at the the end of your main function, ran it in the background, and call `top`. `top` indicated  that the process was using 278 MB of memory.

This seems to indicate that `time` is not working right (somehow).

Comment: @mansfield: To make the `top` resident value (`RES`) measure the memory for the matrix, keep it resident by writing to it in the infinite loop. See my revised program.

Comment: That is a good point. However, I get `VIRT 278m` and `RES 258m` for the updated program and `1057008 KiB` reported by `time`.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I've contacted the cluster staff with the information you gave me and they confirmed that this was what had happened.

Thanks for taking the time to help me track this down.